# Get date value or Unavailable from Table 2, if date value from Table 2 falls within a date range found in Table 1

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have two tables like so:

Table 1

```
Start      | END        | More columns ... 
------------------------------------------
2019-10-20 | 2019-10-21 |...
```

Table 2

```
Log ID | DATE  
--------------
     1 | 2019-10-20 
     2 | 2019-10-22
```

I want to return a results table which includes all of the columns from Table 1, with an additional column containing the date value from Table 2 if a match is found. Note: It is guaranteed that only 1 match can possibly be found from Table 2.

So the result set should then look like:

```
     Start | End        | MoreCols | Available
----------------------------------------------
2019-10-20 | 2019-10-21 | …        | 2019-10-20
```

Or if no match is found, it should look like this:

```
     Start | End        | MoreCols | Available
----------------------------------------------
2019-10-20 | 2019-10-21 | …        | Unavailable
```

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN`, and replace `NULL` with `Unavailable` using `IFNULL()` or `COALESCE()`.

Answer (score 1):

If no match is found, I would suggest leaving the value as `NULL`.  Otherwise, you have a data type problem -- mixing strings and dates.

You can write the query as:

```
select t1.*,
       (select t2.date
        from table2 t2
        where t2.date between t1.start and t1.end
        limit 1
       ) as available
from table1 t1;
```

You say there is only one match.  The `limit 1` ensures that you do not get an error even if there is more than one match.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I tried to implement this solution. However, instead of cross-referencing against each row (because I'll have many date ranges in t1), it seems to only be taking the first found value from T2 and applying that to each row. For example, I have one row with a date range of 2019-10-20 in T1 and two dates linked to a candidate in T2 with separate dates (2019-10-09, 2019-10-20), but for the resultset, it's applying the newly created Available field with 2019-10-09 for every row, even the row with 2019-10-20 as it's date range. Any insight?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
    Select startdate, 
     enddate,....morecolumns, 
   case when startdate In (Select 
     startdate from table2) t1 where 
      startdate<=t1.enddate then 
     Startdate else 'Unavailable'
     End as 'Availability' from table1;
```

Comment: Hi, where is the consideration for end_date in this script?